# Why my program (with openMP) on my ubuntu server cannot fully use the cpu?

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, g++, openmp, cpu-usage

I found my program (written in C++ with openMP) can only occupy roughly 500% CPU no matter how many threads (say 10, 15, 20) I use. But the same program can use `n*100%` CPU with `n` threads on the other computers. The server's basic configuration is as follows,

1. 20 cores
2. OS: ubuntu server 17.10
3. g++-7.2.0-8ubuntu3

I have "reniced" the program to be of high priority but it is still the same. And another info I can provide is that, from `htop`, there are 1 or 2 "red bars" for each core: I am not sure if this is a normal system occupation.

May I ask is it caused by the wrong server setting or the error of the this version of g++?

Answer (score 0):

Now the problem is solved: I have installed g++-5 on the server and the CPU usage becomes normal. So I guess g++-7 (openMP) is still not very stable?